# How to propagate exception from inner doOnError into outer doOnError?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have `pay` method in which i should call initiatePayment and `onSuccess` i should call `confirmPayment`.
In case of any exception in any of the two calls, the it should emit an exception

```
public Single<PayResponse> pay(PayRequest apiRequest) {

            return client.initiatePayment(apiRequest)
                    .doOnSuccess(initiatePaymentResponse -> {
                        client.confirmPayment(initiatePaymentResponse.getPaymentId())
                                .doOnSuccess(confirmPaymentResponse -> doConfirmationLogic(confirmPaymentResponse ))
                                .doOnError(ex -> {ex.printStackTrace();logError(ex);});
                    })

                    .doOnError(ex -> {ex.printStackTrace();logError(ex);});
        }
```

In my cited code an error occurs in `confirmPayment` but `initiatePayment` continues normally.

How can I propagate the exception from the inner **`doOnError`** to the outer **`doOnError`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**doOnXxx**() methods are for callback purposes only and they don't involve on the streaming pipeline that's why they are called "side-effect methods". so there is no way to propagate an error from doOnXxx() to the upstream.

An Error is always a terminal events in Rx world the pipeline is cancelled whenever an error occurs so there is no need to do something into doOnSuccess() method to be sure that everything is "ok" by far. So instead of nesting your code into doOnSuccess() chain you can simply write this way:

```
/*
        you can deal with errors using these operators:

        onErrorComplete
        onErrorResumeNext
        onErrorReturn
        onErrorReturnItem
        onExceptionResumeNext
        retry
        retryUntil
        retryWhen
         */
        return client.initiatePayment(apiRequest)
                //if in initiatePayment was error this will send cancel upstream and error downstream
                .map(initiatePaymentResponse -> { client.confirmPayment(initiatePaymentResponse.getPaymentId());})
                //if in confirmPayment was error this never happens
                .map(confirmPaymentResponse -> doConfirmationLogic(confirmPaymentResponse))
                //every error in this pipeline will trigger this one here
                .doOnError(ex -> {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    logError(ex);
                });
```

Comment: That is very helpful explanation